# SimpleImputer still returning NaN values in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, nan

I am trying to create a linear regression model but first I am trying to use SimpleImputer to replace the NaN values with the columns mean. After I run the code, there is still NaN values. I have the following code:

```
# ########## Modeling ###########

# pipe model and SimpleImputer
model = make_pipeline(SimpleImputer(missing_values =np.nan, strategy='mean'),
                  LinearRegression())

# split the data into train/test:
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3,
                                               random_state=42)
# # print shape:
print("Training data is", X_train.shape)
print("Training target is", X_test.shape)
print("test data is", X_test.shape)
print("test target is", y_test.shape)
X_train
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is old but I had a similar issue. Changing `SimpleImputer(missing_values = None)` worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

`missing_values` for `SimpleImputer` class should be set to `np.nan`(not to `NaN` as in your code)

`NaN` is a string while `np.nan` represents null value.

You should use `NaN` only if your null values are represented as string `NaN`

[Official docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html)

> **missing_values: number, string, np.nan (default) or None**
>
> The placeholder
> for the missing values. All occurrences of missing_values will be
> imputed. For pandas’ dataframes with nullable integer dtypes with
> missing values, missing_values should be set to np.nan, since pd.NA
> will be converted to np.nan.

Comment: I tried using np.nan but still leaving NaN values. I just checked the data type of those columns and they're set to float. Do I need to change these? Sorry, I am new to Python. Thanks!

Comment: If the datatype of column is float then it is represented as `np.nan` so you should use `missing_values =np.nan` (not 'np.nan' but np.nan)

Comment: yeah I have missing_values = np.nan but still giving me NaN values.

Comment: @AlexNavarro can you please share your full code (model training and when you are seeing nans again)

Comment: I updated my code, after I try to run X_train to see if the values are still showing NaN. The picture is what I see. thanks!

Comment: Please add your code to the question that calls `model` pipeline to impute and train the model